# Determine the automorphism group $Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13}, \sqrt[3]{7})/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> **Question**: Determine the automorphism group $$Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13}, \sqrt[3]{7})/\mathbb{Q}).$$

My attempt:
Since the polynomial $(x^2-13)(x^3-7)$ has roots 
$$\sqrt{13}, -\sqrt{13}, \sqrt[3]{7}, \sqrt[3]{7}\omega, \sqrt[3]{7}\omega^2$$
where $\omega$ is the cube root of unity. 
Since the extension does not contain all roots, so the extension is not Galois.

However, I do not know how to determine the automorphism group.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: An automorphism of the field must send a root to another root of the same multiplicity. How may ways can the roots be permuted?

Comment: @JoelPereira only $3$ ways to permute $\sqrt{13},$ $-\sqrt{13}$ and $\sqrt[3]{7}$ as other roots are not in the extension?

Comment: And what three ways do you know of permuting those three roots you've written down?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sigma \in Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13},\sqrt[3]{7})/\mathbb{Q})$, then $\sigma$ is uniquely determine by $\sigma(\sqrt{13})$ and $\sigma(\sqrt[3]{7})$.

Since $\sigma(\alpha) \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13},\sqrt[3]{7}) \;\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13},\sqrt[3]{7})$, we have that $\sigma(\sqrt[3]{7})$ is both a root of $x^3-7$ and an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13},\sqrt[3]{7})$.

This implies that $\sigma(\sqrt[3]{7}) = \sqrt[3]{7}$, since the other roots of $x^3-7$ do not lies in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13},\sqrt[3]{7})$.

Clearly $\sigma(\sqrt{13}) \in \lbrace \pm \sqrt{13} \rbrace$.

In conclusion, we see that $\sigma$ is completely determined by its behaviour on $\sqrt{13}$, and we can easily determine the automorphism group $Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13},\sqrt[3]{7})/\mathbb{Q})$

Comment: Just a quick question. How many element does the automorphism group have?

Comment: Exactlu two: one that maps $\sqrt{13}$ to itself, and one which maps $\sqrt{13}$  to $-\sqrt{13}$. Hope it's clear.